# Why back button is not working to return back from ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using SecondView programmatically. I click the button in ViewController to open SecondView controller, but now I want to back to ViewController from SecondView. I do not have storyboard in SecondView and I want to click the closeButton to go back to ViewController. My code work but when I click the close button it does not work. Any idea?

```
import UIKit

class SecondView: UIViewController {
   

  var closeButton = UIButton()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     
    closeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dismissActionSheet), for: .touchUpInside)
  }
   
  @objc func dismissActionSheet() {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
   }

}
```

Comment: If you present second view controller, then you need to dismiss view controller to go back to previous screen

Comment: yes sure, but for dismiss not work, any suggestion?

Comment: can you also share your code when you move to secondview

Comment: I used " @IBAction func goSecond(_ sender: Any) {
        let controller = SecondView()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }", because viewcontroller have storyboard, but secondview  dont have storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are instantiating a new `UIButton`, adding a target, but never adding the button to the UI. If you are seeing a button in your UI, it must be one that you added in Interface Builder, not the one you reference here. I suspect your intent was not:

```swift
var closeButton = UIButton()
```

but rather:

```swift
@IBOutlet var closeButton: UIButton!
```

… and hook that button’s outlet in IB.

---

Or better, rather than adding a target in `viewDidLoad`, hook up an `@IBAction` for the button directly in IB:

```swift
@IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: Any) {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

You don't appear to need the `closeButton` outlet (at least for what you have shared with us thus far).

---

By the way, `popViewController` only works if this is embedded in a navigation controller. If you are not using a navigation controller (i.e., you “presented” the view controller rather than “pushing” one), the `navigationController` will be `nil` (and `navigationController?.popViewController` will do nothing). If not using navigation controller, call `dismiss` rather than `popViewController`.

Comment: tnx so so much for ur great explanation, let me try to apply :)

Comment: I have Navigation Controller with main storyboard, when I click the button in ViewController it is open SecondView, and in second view I have custom close button on top navigation, when I click the custom close button, I want to back to main view.

Comment: If that custom back button is in the storyboard, then you don’t want `var closeButton = UIButton()` as that will not reference the button in the storyboard but rather creates yet another button that is never added to the UI. So, don’t instantiate a new `UIButton` but rather hook up an `@IBOutlet` or an `@IBAction` in IB (as described in the first half of my answer).

Comment: tnx so much,  let me apply:)

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the Second view programmatically:

Why not set a frame to the button and add it to self.view?

eg:

```
 let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 80, height: 40))
  button.setTitle("Pop VC", for: .normal)
  button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTouched), for: .touchUpInside)

  self.view.addSubview(button)
```

then try to pop back:

```
func btnTouched(sender: UIButton!) {
  if let navController = self.navigationController {
    navController.popViewController(animated: true)
  }
}
```

Comment: tnx so so much , but still not solve problem :)

Comment: If you have added a close button in navigation bar, then its probably UIBarButtonItem? I dont think you have shared the updated source.